# How do you use the # character as a CSS id selector in Atom text editor?

Tags: css, atom-editor

So I'm in a class for html/css and I'm using Atom as my text editor. This week we are learning about css basics. The id selector example is written in the book like this:

```
#feature { color: #333333; }
```

but in atom its like this:

[orange hashmark in atom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNMCK.png)

it seems to viewing it as a comment/ something hidden rather than css. I looked at the keybinding and it supposed to work. Not sure whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

If #feature is an id, you forgot to close the bracket before it.

```
body {background-color: #8590AA;}
#feature {color: #333333;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put in HTML for example `<div id="feature"></div>,` link correctly your CSS stylesheet to your HTML with the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` in the `<head>` (make sure the path to your CSS stylesheet is correct in the attribute `href`). If everything is done correctly then the `#feature` in your CSS should work. Have you closed the "}" after have given `background-color` to your body? Because from your picture it seems not.
I give you a final tip to write your CSS correctly.

Write like this:

```
#feature { 
  color: #333333; 
}
```

Everywhere you'll find CSS written this way. Going forward in your path to become a web developer you'll understand why.